# How do you resolve several-levels-indirect missing dependency hell in Maven/Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, jai, aspose.words, build-dependencies

We have a project which depends on Aspose Words' `com.aspose:aspose-words:16.10.0:jdk16`.

The POM for `aspose-words` declares no dependencies, but this turns out to be a lie. It actually uses `jai-core`, latest version of which is at `javax.media:jai-core:1.1.3`.

The POM for `jai-core`, though, also lies - it declares no dependencies, but actually depends on `jai-codec`, which is at `com.sun.media:jai-codec:1.1.3`.

Getting these projects to fix things seems impractical. JAI is basically a dead project and Maven Central have no idea who added that POM so there is nobody responsible for fixing the metadata. Aspose refuse to fix things without a test reproducing it, even if you can show them their own code doing it wrong, and even if they fixed it, they would then add their dependency on `jai-core:1.1.3`, which only fixes half the problem anyway.

If I look at our entire tree of dependencies, this is only one example of the problem. Others are lurking, masked out by other dependency chains coincidentally pulling in the missing dependency. In some cases, we have even reported POM issues to projects, only for them to say that the dependency "isn't real", despite their classes clearly referring to a class in the other library.

I can think of a few equally awkward options:

- Create `jai-core:1.1.3.1` and `aspose-words:16.10.0.1` and fix their POMs to include the missing dependencies, but whoever updates them in the future will have to do the same thing. Plus, any *other* library I don't know about which happens to depend on `jai-core` would also have to be updated.
- Add a dependency from our own project, even though it really isn't one.
- Edit the POM for the versions which are there now to fix the problem directly, only caveat being that people might have cached the wrong one.

So I guess I have two related questions about this:

- Is there no *proper* way to resolve this? It seems like any non-toy project would eventually hit this problem, so there not being an obviously correct way to deal with it is worrying.
- Is there a way to stop incorrect dependency metadata getting into the artifact server in the first place? It's getting kind of out of hand, because other devs on the team are adding the dependencies without checking things properly, and then I'm left to clean up their error when something breaks a year later.

Comment: You can use the Enforcer plugin to fail the build if specific dependencies are used... but each library is maintained by its team.. If they refuse to fix things, then fork it and fix it yourself is the way to go. It does mean you have to merge new additions of the original into your own fork in a regular manner. But if it's dead anyway... there won't be any. But Aspose is not open source I think? So there may be licensing issues anyways. Another solution: create a wrapper POM, with the dependency on Aspose and every library it needs, then depend on this wrapper POM.

Comment: Please read about [additional dependencies of Aspose.Words](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsjava/System+Requirements#SystemRequirements-AdditionalDependencies). Could you please share complete detail of your use case? I will then provide you more information about your query. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: @TahirManzoor in this particular situation, we were using Aspose to convert DOC to PDF. One DOC happened to contain a BMP, and for some reason Aspose used JAI to read the BMP. It seems to be a legacy thing because I can't get modern versions of Word to create such documents, so I was waiting on some more info on which version of Word created it, so that maybe I could dig up a VM with that version and try to make a test file.

Answer (score 1):

Tunaki has already given many good approaches. Let me add the following:

We had to deal with a lot of legacy jars which are some old or strange versions of already existing jars on MavenCentral. We gave them a special kind of version number (like 1.2.3-companyname) and created a POM for them that fitted our purposes. This is - more or less - your first "awkward option". This is what I would go for in your case; additionally, I would define the version in the dependencyManagement, so that Maven dependency mediation will not set it to some other version.

If a new version of your jar comes around, you can check if it still has the same problems (if they did a correct Maven build, they should have all dependencies inside the POM). If so, you need to fix it again.

I wouldn't change poms for already existing versions because it confuses people and may lead to inconsistency problems because Maven will not grab the new POM if an old version is already in the local repository. Adding the dependency to your own project is an option if you have very few projects to manage so that you still see what is going on (a proper comment on the dependencies in the POM could make it clearer).

Answer (score -1):

JAI is optional for Aspose.Words for Java. Aspose.Words for Java uses JAI image encoders and decoders only if they available. And it will work okay without JAI.

The codecs complement standard java ImageIO encoders/decoders. The most notable addition is support of Tiff.

JAI (Java Advanced Imaging) is not usual library. First of all - it is native library. I.e. it has separate distributives for different platforms. It has also "portable" pure-java distributive, but if you want full power of JAI - you should stick to native option.

Another thing: usually you should run installation of JAI native distributive on the host system. I.e. it installed like desktop application, not like usual java library. Again, JAI codec acts not like usual library: if it installed on system - it will plug into ImageIO, irrelevant to classpath.

So, i don't know good way to install JAI using Maven - it is like using Maven to install Skype or any other desktop application. But it is IMHO, I am not great specialist on Maven:)

Comment: In this particular case it was using JAI to read a BMP, because the document happened to contain one. And if you don't have JAI, you get a failure trying to save such a document to PDF. So "it will work okay" is a bit misleading... it will only work okay if you don't happen to run into a document with a BMP in it. And you can't know in advance whether a document you've been given will trigger the issue.

Comment: Does it insert "red cross" image instead of non-supported/broken image? If yes - it is okay. Anyway, you better to ask your question on Aspose.Words support forum https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx . May be your system can load your type of BMP without JAI - in this case it is a bug.

Comment: It doesn't produce a PDF at all, because you get a failure. We did already post on the forum about it, but they asked for a sample. Nobody would give us a sample either, and Aspose itself cannot be used to create a document with a BMP inside it, because they convert it to PNG automatically.

Comment: "Ask a sample" - is a standard practice - they should reproduce your bug to fix it.

PDF does not support BMP so the BMP should be converted to something other - PNG is okay.

Comment: No, what I meant was that it can't insert a BMP into a DOC. DOC can natively store BMP files, obviously, as the presence of a BMP file causes the issue. The problem is that I can't create sample data using their library, and the person who reported the problem to us refuses to hand over their document as well. :/

Comment: I can only repeat: if support developer can't reproduce your bug - it is not a bug. And I know exactly that Aspose.Words _can_ insert BMP into Doc or any other supported format.

Comment: It inserts it, but it converts it to PNG in the process instead of leaving it as BMP. And we know it's a bug, because we can disassemble the class file and see them loading something that they claim they aren't using.

Comment: Please note that Aspose.Words mimics the same behavior as MS Word does. If you insert the BMP into Word document using MS Word, it will be converted to PNG. Unfortunately, it is difficult to say what the problem is without document and simplified application. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.